# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples?

Tags: python, machine-learning

When trying to execute my code i get the following error

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [92001, 1]
```

I understand that it's some sort of format error but i don't know how to solve it.

Also I have searched every other question and each one have different code than mine so it would be great if any one helps me to rectify it.

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
print(dataset.head())
x = dataset.iloc[:1,:-1]
y = dataset.iloc[:1,-1]

print(y[0:5])
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
y = label_encoder.fit_transform(y.values)
y = y.T
print(x.shape)
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x.values,y)
print(y.shape)
print(np.unique(y))

# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)

# load dataset

# encode class values as integers

# convert integers to dummy variables (i.e. one hot encoded)
dummy_y = np_utils.to_categorical(y)
# define baseline model
def baseline_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=4, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=baseline_model, epochs=200, batch_size=5, verbose=0)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
results = cross_val_score(estimator, X, dummy_y, cv=kfold)
print("Baseline: %.2f%% (%.2f%%)" % (results.mean()*100, results.std()*100))
```

> ```
> Traceback:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
>   File "<ipython-input-12-318474aa38f5>", line 1, in <module>
>     runfile('/Users/vivanksharma/Downloads/temp.py', wdir='/Users/vivanksharma/Downloads')
>
>   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py",
> ```
>
> line 705, in runfile
>           execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> ```
>   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py",
> ```
>
> line 102, in execfile
>           exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> ```
>   File "/Users/vivanksharma/Downloads/temp.py", line 57, in <module>
>     results = cross_val_score(estimator, X, dummy_y, cv=kfold)
>
>   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py",
> ```
>
> line 342, in cross_val_score
>           pre_dispatch=pre_dispatch)
>
> ```
>   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py",
> ```
>
> line 192, in cross_validate
>           X, y, groups = indexable(X, y, groups)
>
> ```
>   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py",
> ```
>
> line 229, in indexable
>           check_consistent_length(*result)
>
> ```
>   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py",
> ```
>
> line 204, in check_consistent_length
>           " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
>
> ```
> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [92001, 1]
> ```

Comment: You are missing the semicolon ( : ) before -1 on your y in line 4...

Comment: @SeraphWedd now it's saying bad `raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))

ValueError: bad input shape (92000, 1024)`

Comment: @SeraphWedd any help ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43971588/python-sklearn-linear-regression-value-error is this related? Have yor tried?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47661488/10416716